# How to control Revolute joint using input button?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, revolute-joints

I am trying to rotate a body connect via revolute joint, when space bar button is pressed in my desktop.it is working fine when i put all the condition in create, but not working on pressing space bar button.
here is my create method

```
            ballBody =createBall();//first body to the joint
            rectBody=createRect();//second body to the joint

            revoluteJointDef = new RevoluteJointDef();
            revoluteJointDef.initialize(ballBody,rectBody,new Vector2(0,0));
            revoluteJointDef.lowerAngle=0;
            revoluteJointDef.upperAngle=0.785f;
            revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA.set(2,0);
            revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.set(0,6);
            revoluteJointDef.collideConnected=false;

            revoluteJointDef.lowerAngle=-0.734f;
            revoluteJointDef.upperAngle=0.735f;
            revoluteJointDef.maxMotorTorque=100f;
            revoluteJointDef.motorSpeed=-12.6f;
            revoluteJointDef.referenceAngle=0f;
            revoluteJointDef.enableLimit=true;
            joint = world.createJoint(revoluteJointDef);
```

and i am enabling motor after pressing space bar button like this

```
  public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if(keycode== Input.Keys.SPACE) {
                   hit();  // call to hit function
        }
```

here is hit function

```
  private void hit(){
        revoluteJointDef.enableMotor=true;
        }
```

and my render method is like this

```
 public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        world.step(1f/60f, 6, 2);
        debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
        game.batch.begin();
         game.batch.end();
    }
```

please help me out with any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found mistake in your Create method last line it should be like

```
revoluteJoint=(RevoluteJoint)world.createjoint(revolutejointDef);
```

and in hit method or else than create method use revolutejoint instead revolutejointDef

```
revoluteJoint.enableMotor=true;
```